# Groups laravel blade template table by input value

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, html-table, laravel-blade

I have database that shows like this:

[image: show database]

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="datatable-default">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Kode MTK</th>
            <th>Nama Mata Kuliah</th>
            <th>Status TM</th>
            <th>Kode Bahan Ajar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @if(!empty($caripaketsemester))
    <tbody>
        @foreach($caripaketsemester as $key => $row)
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><center><?php echo $row->semester ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $row->kode_mtk ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $row->nama_mtk ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $row->status_tm ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $row->kode_bahan_ajar ?></center></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    @else
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endif
</table>
```

Question:  I want to make table that groups by "semester". How do I do that?

I want to be like this:

> Semester 6: Kode MTK | Nama Mata Kuliah | Status TM | Kode Bahan Ajar
>   Semester 8: Kode MTK | Nama Mata Kuliah | Status TM | Kode Bahan Ajar

*one table per semester

Comment: My answer below should work for you.  You might wanna actually do a DB unique query to pull the actual unique semesters from your DB. (group by unique)  But if its a set amount, or you know the amount of semesters then using just a plain Array like I show, will suffice.

Comment: it worked man, thanks. now how can i set te label per semester <p>Semester :</p>

Comment: <p>Semester : {{$s}}</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something along these lines...

You'll want to return your actual semesters from the DB instead of just an array of numbers.  But you get the idea

```
<?php $semesters = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");?>

@foreach($semesters as $s)
// Loop through semesters array and display a table for each
//  Notice I give each table a unique ID. You wouldn't ba allowed to have database-default for all.  As ID's must be unique
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="semester-{{$s}}">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Semester</th>
               <th>Kode MTK</th>
               <th>Nama Mata Kuliah</th>
               <th>Status TM</th>
               <th>Kode Bahan Ajar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @if(!empty($caripakesemester))
      // Loop through your data, and check semester value against $row->semester
     // Display if matches
      @foreach($caripakesemester as $key=>$row)
        @if($row->semester == $s)
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><center>{{$row->semester}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{$row->kode_mtk}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{$row->nama_mtk}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{$row->status_tm}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{$row->kode_bahan_ajar}}</center></td>
        </tr>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    @else
        <tr class="gradeX">
          <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
          <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
          <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
          <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
          <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
        </tr>
    @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i got an error syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH);

Comment: Well don't just copy and paste....I haven't checked syntax or anything.  Take the idea, and apply it yourself.  Also....it works for me.  So you're obviously missing something.  You mightve copied it before I added the closing ;?> at the top?  Check that the $semester array line has the closing ;?>